# How to pass cmake runtime parameter in yocto

Tags: yocto, bitbake

I am working on yocto, I have a component which I am compiling manually using cmake command. I need to select some options using cmake while compiling. `cmake -Dex=on ...`, which enables "ex"

Now I am trying to do the same in the yocto, for compilation I used inherit cmake in bb file, but I am not to pass this option `-Dex=on`

My bb file looks like this

```
SECTION = "devel"

LICENSE = "CLOSED" SRC_URI = "file://*"

SRC_URI = "gitsm://****.git;protocol=ssh"

SRCREV="${AUTOREV}"

S = "${WORKDIR}/git"

inherit cmake
```

How can pass cmake options in the bitbake file?

Comment: can you try setting `EXTRA_OECMAKE += "-Dex=on"` after `inherit cmake`?

Comment: Or now that i think about it, could be before `inherit cmake` too

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You define the extra symbol by setting

```
EXTRA_OECMAKE += "-Dex=on"
```

when you have `inherit cmake` in your recipe.

The variable is used by the `cmake.bbclass` when cmake is called.

Comment: Small correction: before or after, order doesn't matter.